# whether can combine jquery each function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $(function() {
    $('.button-a').each(function() {
      $(this).hover(
        function () {
          $('.button-title', this).animate({ opacity: 0.6 }, 200);
        });
      });
   });
$(function() {
  $('.button-b').each(function() {
    $(this).hover(
      function () {
        $('.button-title', this).animate({ opacity: 0.6 }, 200);
      });
    });
  });
$(function() {
  $('.button-c').each(function() {
    $(this).hover(
      function () {
        $('.button-title', this).animate({ opacity: 0.6 }, 200);
      });
    });
  });
$(function() {
  $('.button-d').each(function() {
    $(this).hover(
      function () {
        $('.button-title', this).animate({ opacity: 0.6 }, 200);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I have many buttons, when hover each, there will have some opacity change.

The codes are similar, the small different is `$('.button-a'),$('.button-b'),$('.button-c'),$('.button-d')`, whether can combine jquery each function?  so that I can shorter my code? Thanks.

Comment: First, you don't need to wrap every piece of code in a jQuery "ready" setup - you've already got **everything** inside a "ready" handler!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two simplifications:

```
var fn = function() {
   $(this).hover(
       function () {
          $('.button-title', this).animate({ opacity: 0.6 }, 200);
       }
   });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button-a').each(fn);
    $('.button-b').each(fn);
    $('.button-c').each(fn);
    $('.button-d').each(fn);
});
```

You can shorten the on-ready call too:

```
var fn = function() {
   $(this).hover(
       function () {
          $('.button-title', this).animate({ opacity: 0.6 }, 200);
       }
   });
});

$(function() {
    $('.button-a').each(fn);
    $('.button-b').each(fn);
    $('.button-c').each(fn);
    $('.button-d').each(fn);
});
```

And you can merge selectors:

```
var fn = function() {
   $(this).hover(
       function () {
          $('.button-title', this).animate({ opacity: 0.6 }, 200);
       }
   });
});

$(function() {
   $('.button-a, .button-b, .button-c, .button-d').each(fn);
});
```

Now, you don't really need `.each`, as `.hover` will automatically apply to each element given by the selector:

```
$(function() {
   $('.button-a, .button-b, .button-c, .button-d').hover(function () {
       $('.button-title', this).animate({ opacity: 0.6 }, 200);
   });
});
```

Take your pick!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`multiple-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) .

```
$(function() {
  $('.button-a,.button-b,.button-c,.button-d').hover(function () {
        $('.button-title', this).animate({ opacity: 0.6 }, 200);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything different about these functions, opacity included. But you can group selectors in the jQuery call, like:

```
$('.button-a,.button-b,.button-c,.button-d')...
```

You can also use [`jQuery.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) if you don't have the selectors initially, but want to add them to the chain later on. e.g.

```
$('.button-a,.button-b,.button-c').add('.button-d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

```
$('.button-a,.buttcon-b,.button-c,.button-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
$('.button-a, .button-b, .button-c, .button-d').each(function() {
  $(this).hover(function() {
    $('.button-title', this).animate({ opacity: 0.6 }, 200);
  });
});
```

As I said in a comment, it's not necessary to use

```
$(function() {
  // code code code ...
});
```

all the time.  You've already got everything inside a "ready" handler.